# HTML5 input type="color" styling

Tags: css, html, forms

Just discovered that there is a color input type in HTML5, I guess i have never needed it before so never noticed it.

Unfortunately chrome adds an ugly grey dead space around the colour swatch that isn't there in Firefox. Any way I can get rid of this?

[Code is here](http://codepen.io/rachelreveley/pen/ZOXNgO)

```
<form>
  <input type="color" />
</form>

input[type="color"] {padding: 0; margin: 0; border: 0;}
```

Comment: Nope...it's a browser object...you have very limited styling options. The color picker has almost none as I recall.

Comment: You can't even call `appearance: none` on this element! `:(`

Comment: I don't know why this was marked as duplicate, because this question is about the appereance of the color picker button and not of the actual color picker. Anyway. I found out that setting the `background-color` to `transparent` gets rid of the grey area. http://codepen.io/Demnogonis/pen/dXVBym

Comment: You can use [webkit specific CSS selectors](https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/Styling%20Form%20Controls). Check this [updated pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kXGKWX) for example.

Comment: Thanks  Demnogonis That was the one thing I didn't try despite seeeming obvious now. I agree the other thread doesn't answer my question at all.

Comment: Here is an nice answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11167281/webkit-css-to-control-the-box-around-the-color-in-an-inputtype-color