# Remove border around the color in an input[type=color] in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I want to remove the border around the color of input[type=color] in Firefox. I found solution for Chrome [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11167281/webkit-css-to-control-the-box-around-the-color-in-an-inputtype-color) (use ::-webkit-color-swatch in CSS) and I need it for Firefox and Microsoft Edge too. Thank you!

For example, in this picture, I want to remove the black border around the pink color, not the blue border of input (this blue border is the form-control class of Bootstrap and I don't ask about it)
[image: picture]

Comment: You should be careful with changes like these. Users that navigate your website by keyboard won't have an indicator where the current focus is. Same goes for visually impaired users.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's similar to `::-webkit-color-swatch`.

```
::-moz-color-swatch {
    border-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

if anybody faces this issue this worked for me:

```css
input[type="color"] {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 5px solid #DDD;
}

input[type="color"]::-moz-color-swatch {
  border: none;
}

input[type="color"]::-webkit-color-swatch-wrapper {
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}

input[type="color"]::-webkit-color-swatch {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="color">
```

will be providing an pure css generator [here](https://antvil.github.io/css-sos/sos/color/index.html)

Answer (score 5):

It would be better to make it common for all, Try this:

```
input[type="text"]{
    border: none;
    border-color: transparent;
}
```

or

If focus is on the `input` field, Use this:

```
input[type="text"]:focus{
    outline: none;
}
```

Post your code if this is'nt what you're looking for!

**Update**

Put your code inside `::-moz-color-swatch{ }`

Comment: thanks but I don't asked about the border of input, I edited my question, please check it

Comment: As suggested by @int32_t ::-moz-color-swatch is working. Check that once!

Answer (score 0):

You can add `border-color: transparent` to the input box.