# How to Change HTML5 Color Input Inner Radius

Tags: javascript, css, html

Trying to make the native HTML5 color input into a simple round circle, seems like the border and padding can be manipulated which is a good thing, I am looking for a way to `border-radius` the inner color...

```css
#color1{
  padding:10px;
  border:none;
  border-radius:10px;
}

#color2{
  background:none;
  border:none;
}
```

```html
<input type="color" id="color1" />
<input type="color" id="color2" />
```

Comment: Are you just looking for `border: 10px solid [color];`? That gives the colour as the border, but creates a middle 'layer'.

Comment: I was looking for a way to change the inner border of the input element...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's no good cross-browser way of doing this; browsers just don't expose the necessary hooks, except Chrome (and maybe Safari and other WebKit-based browsers). Firefox has some support, outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38821432/215552).

The following will work in Chrome 55. It was compiled from a number of sources, most notably from [Keishi Hattori](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1523640/keishi-hattori)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11471224/215552)

```css
#color1 {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
#color1::-webkit-color-swatch {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 0;
}
#color1::-webkit-color-swatch-wrapper {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="color" id="color1" />
```

Comment: your solution is a nice one, but for better compatibility, check the snippet in my answer.

Comment: this solution is the cleanest one, I'll put it in mind for hopefully the near future when compatibility is better.

Answer (score 7):

1. Wrap the `input` in a `div`.
2. Add `border-radius` and `overflow` property to the `div`.

That seems to be enough for Firefox.. 
For Chrome:

3. Add `width` and `height` 200% to the `input`
4. Reposition the `input` using `transform`

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

[type="color"] {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translate(-25%, -25%)
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="color">
</div>
```

Comment: I believe this is the safest way for it to look the same in all browsers

Comment: Good solution for all browsers :)

Comment: Not all heroes wear caps, Saved the day. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved neatly with the following snippet, which sets the opacity of input to 0 (invisible) and sets the background of the parent div to the selected color.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#color1').on('input', function() {
    $(this).parent().css({
      background: $(this).val()
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#color1 {
  border: none;
  opacity: 0;
}

.rounded {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rounded">
  <input type="color" id="color1" />
</div>
```

[jQuery](https://jquery.com/) is being used for changing the background of the parent to the selected color - credits goes to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25650208/5838198) for the 'input' event handler.

Having that said, if you also want a second color as in your snippet, just put another div as parent of `.rounded` and set the color to your preference.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#color1').on('input', function() {
    $(this).parent().css({
      background: $(this).val()
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#color1 {
  border: none;
  opacity: 0;
}
.rounded,
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.rounded {
  background: black;
}
.wrapper {
  padding: 10px;
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="rounded">
    <input type="color" id="color1" />
  </div>
</div>
```

This snippet will work in all the modern browsers versions, including IE 10. See [the CanIUse page](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-event) for more information on compatibility.