# Input type color styling

Tags: html, css

I have a small question, since I'm not too good at CSS i want to know if there any way I can recreate such a nice input[type=color] element's style? I mean not everything on the screenshot but only that pretty circle which is input[type=color].

[image]

Here I have some code that was written with it but it's not styling the input[type=color] like on a screenshot... Also I have seen that the author  uses Vue.js in his project... Thank you very much for help!

```
<input type="color" id="primary_color" class="field-radio" name="primary-color" v-model="scheme.primary" @change="changeColor()">
```

```css
input[type="color"] {
    width: 3rem;
    height: 3rem;
    padding: .5rem;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
input[type="color" i] {
    -webkit-appearance: square-button;
    width: 44px;
    height: 23px;
    background-color: buttonface;
    cursor: default;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgb(169, 169, 169);
    border-image: initial;
    padding: 1px 2px;
}
input {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
    cursor: text;
    padding: 1px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: inset;
    border-color: initial;
    border-image: initial;
}
input, textarea, select, button {
    text-rendering: auto;
    color: initial;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-shadow: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: start;
    margin: 0em;
    font: 400 13.3333px Arial;
}
input, textarea, select, button, meter, progress {
    -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
}
```

Comment: Where's the html?

Comment: @Highdef Added html, sorry for that

Comment: Have a look at the answer provided here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11167281/webkit-css-to-control-the-box-around-the-color-in-an-inputtype-color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11167281/webkit-css-to-control-the-box-around-the-color-in-an-inputtype-color)

Comment: @Andreas yeah, thanks, I've watched through it before, but this method provides a small awkward border that can't be removed

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is the code you need:

```js
let colorButton = document.getElementById("primary_color");
let colorDiv = document.getElementById("color_val");

colorButton.oninput = function() {
    colorDiv.innerHTML = colorButton.value;
    colorDiv.style.color = colorButton.value;
}
```

```css
#primary_color{
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

#primary_color::-webkit-color-swatch-wrapper {
    padding: 0; 
}
#primary_color::-webkit-color-swatch {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <input type="color" id="primary_color" class="field-radio">
    <span class="container" id="color_val"></span>
</div>
```

Basically, it will find the `colorButton` in the DOM and listen to the `input` event on this element. When it fires, the text and the color of the text will be updated.

Comment: note: default padding is not necessary even for `input[type=color]` (seems to be `1px 2px` in Chrome) so make sure to reset it.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure if that's possible with just html and CSS to achieve that. But using Javascript you can cook up something like the following:

- Wrapping the input color tag in a label with border radius 50%.
- Hiding the input and setting  a background to the label.
- Using javascript to change the color of the label depending on the color changed in the input color container.

**Javascript:**

```js
var color_picker = document.getElementById("primary_color");
var color_picker_wrapper = document.getElementById("test_wrapper");
color_picker.onchange = function() {
  color_picker_wrapper.style.background = color_picker.value;
}
```

```css
#primary_color {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#test_wrapper {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, red, orange, yellow, green, blue, violet);
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 1px 4px 10px black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="test_wrapper"><input type="color" id="primary_color" class="field-radio" name="primary-color" v-model="scheme.primary" @change="changeColor()"> </label>
```

**Jquery:**

```js
$(document).on('change', '#primary_color', function() {
  $("#test_wrapper").css('background', "" + document.getElementById('primary_color').value);
});
```

```css
#primary_color {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#test_wrapper {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, red, orange, yellow, green, blue, violet);
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 1px 4px 10px black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="test_wrapper"><input type="color" id="primary_color" class="field-radio" name="primary-color" v-model="scheme.primary" @change="changeColor()"> </label>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but still I don't have a clue how it works out with JQuery. Just like, if I remove background-color of #test_wrapper it doesn't work...

Comment: @YegorGunko You want to implement it with Jquery?

Comment: @YegorGunko Updated solution for both javascript and jquery.

Comment: like I can't even get to know how it works but your solution is very good, thank you :3

Comment: @YegorGunko Well, we're using the "onchange" event handler to see if the input field color is changed (with the id #primary_color). If it is changed, we obtain that value and apply the same color as background to the label wrapper. But you'll need to learn javascript or jquery to understand what the syntax means.

Comment: well, I'm somewhat familiar with JS and JQuery, still I'll look through your code once again and hope I'll understand, thank you very much)

Comment: @YegorGunko I'm not sure why you changed your marked answer. But pretty sure, the main requirement was for the input type color to be a circle container which from what I see the current answer isn't browser cross compatible (Firefox for instance) .

Answer (score 2):

Note: for Firefox you would need to use -moz-color-swatch
There is no color-swatch-wrapper equivalent on Firefox.

You need to create a new rule, since it's not possible mix vendors prefixed rules (see [Why isn't it possible to combine vendor-specific pseudo-elements/classes into one rule set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16982449/why-isnt-it-possible-to-combine-vendor-specific-pseudo-elements-classes-into-on) )

i.e. add

```css
#primary_color::-moz-color-swatch {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
```

For Firefox to look like what you expect, seems you also need to add `padding: 0px;` on the `#primary_color` section

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input').change(function(){
   var color = $(this).val();
   $('.color-code').html(color);
   $('.color').css({'background':color})
 })
})
```

```css
.color-picker {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  display: block;
}

.color-code {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
  width: 70px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.color {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="color-picker"><input type="color"/>
<div class="color-code">#000000</div><div class="color" style="background:#000000"></div></label>
```

You want to did this with jquery