# Change "fill" of d3 bar graph

Tags: d3.js

I'm learning D3 in Laravel and trying to use this color picking button:

```
<input type="color">
```

...to update the fill of the d3 bar chart at this link:
(https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304)

I have tried numerous solutions, including working with css objects and the answer here:
([Input type color styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47971289/input-type-color-styling))

I get the whole chart loaded on a page but the color picking button, which can change colors like in the answer on the other linked question, doesn't update the graph's fill. To clarify, I was sure to update "fill" and not "color". I'm new to D3 and js but not html and css. Color can be set by adding a line of the following, for example:

```
.attr("fill", "green");
```

... to the end of the code, but I want to see how to change the graph's bar fill by picking a color from the "input type" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a listener to the input for a change event. On a change, select all the bars, then set the fill to the new color.

```
d3.select("input")
  .on("change", function() {
    g.selectAll(".bar")
      .style("fill", d3.select(this).property("value"))
  });
```

Comment: Worked immediately. Thanks for helping me learn. I became aware of the syntax of .onchange needing to be .on("change", ), but this takes care of every other step I wouldn't have found.