# How to style color picker window in an input[type=color]?

Tags: html, css, webkit, color-picker

Is there a way to style color picker window that come after clicking on input[type=color]?

By default it is white in color, I want to change it to black because theme of my website is dark.

```css
input[type='color'] {
  padding: 0;
  width: 150%;
  height: 150%;
  margin: -25%;
}

.cp_wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 0px grey;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="cp_wrapper">
  <input type="color" name="cp_3" value="#8888ff" />
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47971289/input-type-color-styling/47971607

Comment: No. This is related to styling input box. I want to style the window that open when we click on that input box.

Answer (score 1):

I think the color picker window is not part of the browser but the operating system and it changes shape form os to another that's why it is unaccessible but you can import color palette from js libraries or create your own. There is two methods I managed to write dynamic color picker using calculations but there is a way using canvas.

[my color palette](https://anaselkalla.github.io/Custom-Color-palette/)

Comment: Do you happen to have a link to a tutorial showing your technique?