# Rounded <input type='color'>

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, colors

```js
$("#colour").change(function(event) {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```css
input[type=color] {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px; 
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='color' value='#fefefe' class='bar' id='colour'>
```

Even though I made the `<input type='color'>` rounded, when I input a value (at least on safari) it changes the circle to a square instead. How can I do this? thanks.

Comment: overflow:hidden ? and border:none, outline:none ..

Comment: @TemaniAfif Nope, none of them or combinations of them works.

Comment: Webkit has some unofficial CSS selectors that might be useful. Check out the answer here: [Webkit CSS to control the box around the color in an input[type=color\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11167281/webkit-css-to-control-the-box-around-the-color-in-an-inputtype-color#answer-11471224). It [works for me in Chrome](https://jsfiddle.net/yvajmj5t/1/), but of course is not very cross-browser compatible.

Comment: Related reference: [Styling native elements](https://gist.github.com/webtobesocial/aefd6e25064c08e0cc9a#user-content-input-typecolor).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My idea:

1. create one inline-block `<span>`
2. set `input[type=color]` to not visible.
3. bind click event of `<span>` to trigger `<input>.click()`.

Because `<input>` is not friendly for shape customization.

```js
$("#colour").change(function(event) {
    console.log($(this).val());
    $("#color_front").css('background-color',$(this).val());
});

$("#color_front").click(function(event) {
    $("#colour").click();
});
```

```css
input[type=color] {
    display: none;
}
span {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px; 
  background-color:red;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="color_front"></span>
<input type='color' value='#fefefe' class='bar' id='colour'>
```

Comment: Very nice, and reasonably cross-browser compatible.

Answer (score 6):

In a similar situation earlier, what I did for this was to add two extra styles with pseudo-selectors `::-webkit-color-swatch` and `::-webkit-color-swatch-wrapper`.. Don't know the exact reason..Somehow got this answer at that time (probably from SO itself ;) )..

Add,

```
input[type=color]::-webkit-color-swatch {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 0;
}

input[type=color]::-webkit-color-swatch-wrapper {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 0;
}
```

See the snippet below..

```js
$("#colour").change(function(event) {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```css
input[type=color] {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px; 
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

input[type=color]::-webkit-color-swatch {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 0;
}

input[type=color]::-webkit-color-swatch-wrapper {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='color' value='#fefefe' class='bar' id='colour'>
```

**UPDATE**

I think I got the tutorial from which I got the solution.. [Here](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2013/04/15/list-of-pseudo-elements-to-style-form-controls/#input_color) is it..

Comment: Worth mentioning that:
"This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.", could've saved me some time.

Answer (score 3):

I personally like this solution because it does not involve JS.

```html
<style>
.color-input-wrapper {
  height: 1.5em;
  width: 1.5em;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}
.color-input-wrapper  input[type=color] {
    position: absolute;
    height: 4em;
    width: 4em;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    overflow: hidden;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
</style>
<div class="color-input-wrapper">
     <input type="color">
</div>
```

Comment: I love this. Questoin though, how to make the circle bigger?

Comment: @chitgoks add `scale: 2` to the `.color-input-wrapper' class.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
   input[type="color"] { scale: 3 }

    .input_container {
        width: 2rem;
        height: 2rem;
        border-radius: 50%;
        overflow: hidden;
        border: orange 2px solid;
    }
</style>

<div class="input_contianer">
    <input type="color">
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code, it will definitely work.

```css
 input {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            border-color: black;
            color: black;
            background-color: #fff;
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;

        }

        input[type="color"]::-webkit-color-swatch-wrapper {
            padding: 0;
        }

        input[type="color"]::-webkit-color-swatch {
            border: none;
            border-radius: 10px;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <input type="color" name="color-gradient-1" id="color1" value="#ff0000" />

</body>

</html>
```

Use the following code, it will definitely work

```js
input[type="color"]::-webkit-color-swatch {
            border: none;
            border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: This seems more-or-less (mostly less) identical to [this answer from three years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48832602/19068)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).