# How to stylize input[ type = color ]

Tags: html, css, styles

Is there a way to stylize the input[type=color] field? I want to change its background and size.

[image]

I am talking about the white space around "RGB".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49507878/how-to-style-color-type-input

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11167281/webkit-css-to-control-the-box-around-the-color-in-an-inputtype-color

Answer (score 1):

You can change background and size using CSS

```css
input{
background-color:yellow; height:40px
}
```

```html
<input type="color">
```

Comment: This is not what I was talking about. I wanted to change the color of the dropdown that appears after you click on the color input. Like all the white space around "RGB" and everything.