# Unable to change color of input type=color field using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, colors

I have wrapped my input field of type 'color' in  a label tag to get control over the styling of the input field as nicely suggested in one of the proposed solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11167281/webkit-css-to-control-the-box-around-the-color-in-an-inputtype-color).

So I have something like:

```
"<label class='myLabel1'><input type='color' class='myColor1' value='#ffffff'></input></label>
```

It works as expected. However, if I try to change the color as in:

```
   $('.myColor1').val('#FF0000');
```

It does not change the color of the input field.

Comment: It's working fine for me. What is the exact problem here?

Comment: @SMAKSS  Did you try hiding the field? The color does not change in the styled label. Please refer to the link to understand the exact problem.  If the change in the input field is through the color-picker, it updates the label correctly.  Perhaps my question is wrongly worded.  It is the label that is not updated. I have the on change event but it is not triggered when the color is changed through Javascript.

Comment: @Sunny Please provide a minimal, reproducible example so we can help.

Comment: Seems to work fine! How many `form` elements do you have with the class `myColor1`? That might be the issue.

Comment: @PeterKA The answer lies in the link I provided. I missed the issue completely. See response below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these methods.

```
1. $('.myColor1').attr('value', '#FF0000'); 
2. $('.myColor1').prop('value', '#FF0000');
```

JS:

```
3. var elem = document.querySelector('.myColor1'); 
   elem.setAttribute('value', '#FF0000');
```

Code should not work because when label is used to fake the input field, the label's CSS should be updated through Javascript and not the input field's color.  Label color change also changes the input field's color but not vice versa.

Comment: Unfortunately did not help.

Comment: try this - `$('.myLabel1 .myColor1')...`. If it does not help, then provide your `html` and `css`.

Comment: ... and check on the console if the parameter is passed to the attribute or not. If the parameter is passed, then the problem is different. `console.log($('.myColor1').attr('value'));`